# VMware Fusion 11 macOS monterey : No internet access on guest OS

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

Not able to access internet on guest OS VMware Fusion 11 with mac OS 12 Monterey. The network adapter used is "share with my mac" same works for mac OS 11 but not working on 12. Is shows self-assigned IP.

Any work around?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this release, if we don’t use the NIC type ‘vmxnet3’, we will have issues getting an IP Address in the VM. Locate the below (search “virtualDev” or “e1000e”) in your VM's VMX file (option+right click on your VM, select "Open config file in editor".

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
```

Replace “e1000e” with “vmxnet3”.

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"
```

Once that's done, restart the VM. If this doesn't work, rebuild your VM with this option set from the start.

I have a blog on this topic which should get you going. https://blog.eucse.com/how-to-run-macos-monterey-12-beta-in-vmware-fusion/

Comment: changing ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"  and setting  Bridging to "Auto detect" and then Renew DHCP lease helped from Guest OS network setting helped .

Comment: Thank you! Make sure the VM is shutdown before editing the config file. Otherwise the hypervisor will overwrite the file with previous settings.

Answer (score 2):

If the guest OS is a newly-installed Windows VM (or in the process of installation) and does not detect any network adapters, make sure you have installed VMware Tools. On MacOS, got to `VM -> Install VMware Tools` from the menu bar.

Sources:

- https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Windows-11-ARM-failing-at-Wifi-setup/td-p/2985901
- https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Documents/The-Unofficial-Fusion-13-for-Apple-Silicon-Companion-Guide/ta-p/2939907

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work after making the change on your VMX file, try restarting your PC, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you come here from Google and the accepted answer is not enough to get internet working on MacOS with the latest VMWare Fusion, please consider if you have any installed apps blocking or monitoring network requests.

In my case the otherwise excellent [BlockBlock](https://objective-see.org/products/blockblock.html) was silently blocking VMWare Fusion from bridging the internet connection for all VMs.